# How to add and use silverlight controls in asp net webpage along with other asp.net controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Using Visual Studio 2012 I tried to follow the steps given in the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135987.aspx

for the same I downloaded Silverlight.js file from
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs

but in the very first example of growing and shrinking green sphere I was unable to see expected output. I see a blank white page. Is something I am missing. I tested my silverlight installation, its perfectly running sample silverlight application in browser, so no issue in silverlight version etc. Because the article posted on the link is too old. So there may be some updates or change in way of using. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - that is a very old article, and the method of embedding the Silverlight control in the ASPX page changed at about v3 of Silverlight.

I suggest you watch this instruction video: [Adding Silverlight to a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight/jj730543). Additionally [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight/bb187401) is also a good launch page for learning more about Silverlight.

Comment: Did you go through the video and link or just shared it. I already gone through it and the video link you provided is for same old version (1.0) . Also the tutorial is given of Silverlight javascript application not the asp.net application. Also the another link I already saw while google-ing I didn't find any relevant reference.